# How can I tell if a $("..").each() call was aborted prematurely?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, some psuedo-psuedo-code:

```
$("some-selector-logic").each(function() {
  if (someLogic($(this))) {
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise do stuff related to $(this)
});

someMoreExcitingCode();
```

In this example we're getting a collection of DOM elements based on some selector logic, then iterating over each one. For each element we're calling `someLogic()`. If that returns `true` we abort the each loop. Otherwise, we perform some logic on the element and then move on to the next element. Once we've worked through all the elements we continue on and call `someMoreExcitingCode()`.

I'd like to know, before calling `someMoreExcitingCode()`, whether or not the loop was aborted prematurely. Obviously you can do something like this:

```
var aborted = false;
$("..").each(function() {
  if (someLogic($(this))) {
    aborted = true;
    return false;
  }
});
```

but this feels sloppy to me, like jQuery should be providing me with this information in another way. Is there a more idiomatic way of achieving this that I don't know about?

Comment: I haven't come across any other way to solve this problem

Comment: Why do you need to know? I've never personally ran in to such a requirement, and at first glance it comes off as smelly/leaky. Perhaps there's a better way to solve whatever bigger problem you're working on.

Comment: I guess a variation on what you already have is a counter, but I don't see an advantage from that over what you already have

Comment: A single boolean isn't going to break the bank memory wise, and chances are its probably not going to spaghetti your code either. Those are things I would call "sloppy". +1 for the neat question

Comment: @Mash, sure, though in my concrete case each round of each could possibly invalidate the next one: you can only tell by executing each, so there is no way to filter it out.. though I suppose I could abuse `filter()` and have it perform the action, so the call to filter actually returns the collection of elements that were worked on, which may or may not be all of them. Smells pretty bad though :P

Comment: @bwheeler96, I think it's sloppy because I don't like that the function that is supposed to perform an action on each element has to also manage a concept that is relevant to every object. Note that I don't really mind the code above, I was just writing it and thinking it should probably look a lot nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way jQuery functions tend to return the same collection of objects they were called on (to allow chaining), there's no way for the `each()` function to return that information to you - it's already returning a jQuery object that you can chain other method calls onto.

Based on the information you've provided I don't see a problem with using an external flag or counter variable to get this information. If you tell us a bit more about *why* you need to know this though, we may be able to provide more useful suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing magic about `$.each()`. It's a simple function, and either it does what you need or it doesn't. If it doesn't, there's nothing wrong with setting variables as in your code example. And there's nothing wrong with writing your own `each()` function that does exactly what you need. It's just a few lines of code that runs a loop and calls your callback function.

Here's the source code for `$.each()` in jQuery 1.10.1:

```
// args is for internal usage only
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
    var value,
        i = 0,
        length = obj.length,
        isArray = isArraylike( obj );

    if ( args ) {
        if ( isArray ) {
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                value = callback.apply( obj[ i ], args );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( i in obj ) {
                value = callback.apply( obj[ i ], args );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    // A special, fast, case for the most common use of each
    } else {
        if ( isArray ) {
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( i in obj ) {
                value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
},
```

The only complexity in this code comes from the fact that it handles both objects and arrays, with two different cases for each of those.

For the case you're dealing with, it boils down to:

```
        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
            value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

            if ( value === false ) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

There's just not that much code there, and if doesn't do what you want, you can easily write your own similar iterator that does exactly what you need.

You could even use a simple `for` loop.

```
function doExcitingStuff() {
    var $elements = $("some-selector-logic");
    for( var i = 0;  i < $elements.length;  i++ ) {
        var $element = $($elements[i]);
        if( someLogic($element) )
            return;
        // Otherwise do stuff related to $element
    }
    someMoreExcitingCode();  // only runs if the loop completes
}
```

It really all depends on what makes your code the cleanest. You can either use `$.each()` or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not as elegant as you'd wish, but you can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var aborted = Array.prototype.some.call($(".foo"), function(el) {
    if ($(el).hasClass('bar')) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbtLV/)

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to avoid that `abort` boolean, and you care not about efficiency, then you could do as follows:

```
$("..").removeClass('aborted').each(function() {
    if(someLogic($(this))) {
        $(this).addClass('aborted');
        return false;
    }
});

if( $("..").find('aborted').length ) {
    //each was aborted
}
else {
    //each ran to completion
}
```

But this is effectively using the DOM to register your boolean state as opposed to setting a js var.

Personally, I would bite the bullet and use your `abort = true` idea.